# handling exceptions with linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, exception

How can I handle exceptions in a linq query? For example if I have the following query:

```
var query = (from d in GetLHDb().daily_average
             where d.findnsave_site_id == fnsID 
                   && d.test_path_id == pathId 
                   && d.date > nTimesDays 
                   && d.date <= yesterday
             select new
             {
                 loadtime = d.loadtime,
                 created_at = d.date
             }).ToArray();
```

for instance, how can i handle the null exception inside the query? I have searched online but a lot of them are for VB.

Comment: Where is the null exception coming from?  Is it being thrown from `GetLHDb().daily_average`, or from accessing a variable in `d`?

Comment: Define what you mean that you want to "handle null exception[s]".

Comment: This was just one example but normally it gives me the null exception when the result is empty. I am new to C# Linq so I did not know how to handle such situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, just like you would any other place in your code.  Wrap your `.ToArray()` in a `try/catch` block.  Although in your case I would just be more defensive and handle the null value properly.

```
try
{
    var query = (from d in GetLHDb().daily_average
    where d.findnsave_site_id == fnsID && d.test_path_id == pathId && d.date >                           nTimesDays && d.date <= yesterday
select new { loadtime = d.loadtime, created_at = d.date }).ToArray();
}
catch (Exception)
{
  //do what you need to
}
```

Comment: thanks. this is a neat solution. But let's say I want to further use the results in var `query` outside the try/catch block, this won't let me use `query` because it is only in the scope of try/catch block.

Comment: @SherCoder: In that case, you won't be able to use the `var` keyword.  You will have to strongly type your query object.  After the try/catch block, you will have to check for `query != null` in case the code threw an exception.

Comment: so are you saying just create a separate class that holds the data I want to retrieve from the database?

Comment: @SherCoder: Yes you can do that... there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: is there another way to do that? I am sorry i am new to c# and linq.

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    var query = (from d in GetLHDb().daily_average
    where d.findnsave_site_id == fnsID && d.test_path_id == pathId && d.date > nTimesDays && d.date <= yesterday
    select new { loadtime = d.loadtime, created_at = d.date }).ToArray();
}
catch (NullReferenceException e)
{
    ReportError();
}
```

Comment: thanks but it has the same issue as I mentioned in the above similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, I am seeing three possible places where you could be getting a null-reference exception, and that is from accessing `GetLHDb().daily_average` when GetLHDB is null, trying to enumerate over `daily_average` is null, or trying to access fields within `d` when it is null (*I'm not even sure if this one could happen*).

I would recommend storing the result of `GetLHDb()` to a local variable (for example, `lhdb`), and then doing a null-check on it.  If it is not null, do a nll check-on `lhdb.daily_average`.  If that's not null, continue on with your query.

**Update:** In addition, in case `d` is null, you can start your where clause off with a `d != null`.

```
var lhdb = GetLHDb();
if(lhdb != null && lhdb.daily_average != null)
{
    var query = (from d in lhdb.daily_average
                 where d != null // If d can't be null, remove this
                       && d.findnsave_site_id == fnsID 
                       && d.test_path_id == pathId 
                       && d.date > nTimesDays 
                       && d.date <= yesterday
                 select new
                 {
                     loadtime = d.loadtime,
                     created_at = d.date
                 }).ToArray();

    // Process the results
}
```

Comment: This only checks if the database or the table is empty. But in my case, that is not the case. However, I think it is still a good practice to have that check there.

Comment: I added a clause in case `d` is null, but I don't think you should ever run into that.  If `daily_Average` has no rows, you should just have an empty enumeration and get an empty array as a result of the original query.